# I have a sum of difference between dates in a Sql table. How do I calculate its average in days, hours, minutes?

Tags: sql, average

I have a table with a start time and an end time (datetime, example: 2021-07-09 17:12:00) in each row.

When I calculate the sum of all differences between end time and start time by this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(`end_time`, `start_time`))) AS TimeDiff
FROM 
    my_table
```

I get a result expressed in hours, minutes, seconds (example: 00:02:00)

Now I need to calculate the average time expressed in hours, minutes, seconds of this sum.
It means:

```
SELECT 
    TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(`end_time`, `start_time`))) AS TimeDiff
FROM 
    my_table
```

TimeDiff/number of rows (expressed in hours, minutes, seconds)

Can you help me? Really thanks

Comment: If you're using a DB that can average a time type, then just wrap it in an AVG(). If youre using aDB taht can't, then convert the time into a total number of seconds, average the single integer, then convert back

Comment: Incidentally, it seems that "the sum of all times in a table" would be a single value, so the average is also the same value. Perhaps you should not sum them, but average them instead

Comment: @CaiusJard first of all thanks. The difference between end time and start time is different in each row. For example in the first row is 1 minute. In the second is 3 minutes. The sum of these tow differences is 4 minutes. The average I meen is (1 + 3)/number of rows -> 4/2 = 2 minutes.  You wrote: "convert the time into a total number of seconds, average the single integer, then convert back": how can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried just swapping SUM for AVG? If your DB can sum times, it might be able to average them too. AVG is the equivalent of SUM/COUNT, so if AVG doesn't work, perhaps SUM(...)/COUNT(*) will

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb and guessing you're using MySQL due to the TIMEDIFF function.. Always state what DB you use; SQL is a standard, not a product

You asked about converting times to seconds and back, it probably looks like:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time)))) FROM ...
```

Comment: Hello, realy thanks, it works! Just another question: it returns me a result so expressed:  63:38:33.0313 (Hours: Minutes: Seconds:....). I need to express this value as: Days:Hours:Minutes without secons. Can you help me? Really Really thanks!!!

Comment: You mean like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-convert-a-mysql-time-value-to-days-and-hours-form ?

Comment: First of all thanks. Here what I have: $media = Database::ExecuteScalar("SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(Risolto, Richiesto)))) AS Media FROM socialPm_media_uploads");
echo("Tempo Medio Gestione Ticket: $media");  -- Actually what I see as result is:  63:51:53.4965. I need something like: X Days Y Hours Z Minutes (I don't need seconds as start_time and end_time do not provide seconds). I looked you link (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-convert-a-mysql-time-value-to-days-and-hours-form) it just provides Days and Hours. Could you help me? really really thanks

Comment: Minutes is just `MINUTE(the_time)` e.g. `SELECT FLOOR(HOUR(x)/24) as days, HOUR(x)MOD 24 as hours, MINUTE(x) as mins FROM (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(Risolto, Richiesto)))) AS x FROM socialPm_media_uploads) xx`

Comment: You're simply fantastic!! Really really thanks! It works perfectly!! Tnx!